# sqoop incremental import with merge key

Tags: hadoop, merge, increment, sqoop

The sqoop incremental import job with --merge-key seems to have the following 2 major limitations

> 1. Nested target directory is not supported.
> 2. Two stages are not atomic i.e. even if the second stage fails, the first stage's last value gets updated.

On 1, if a target directory has nested dirs, it throws an error saying that the path is not a file.

Any thoughts on this?

sqoop-merge also seems to have limitation 1 as described above.

Comment: This needs to be addressed. Two stages are not atomic i.e. even if the second stage fails, the first stage's last value gets updated. Ever found a solution to it? My merge job keeps failing all the time. @learninghuman